# Regex after first sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm gonna to write regex or other expression to get coordinates after '='.

My example:

```
var cords = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.082961,19.966860&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false&markers=color:orange%7C50.082961,19.966860&client=gme-marktplaats&channel=bt_pl&signature=lPDQWiNQ2_mY8xgoVthZHLLYWac=
```

I want to get `50.082961,19.966860`

I know that I could use `slice` but I think I could write it better with `regex`.

Simple base for this example: `\=(.[0-9])` What's next?

Comment: Regex is not an appropriate tool for parsing a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `center\=(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)&`

```js
var val = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.082961,19.966860&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false&markers=color:orange%7C50.082961,19.966860&client=gme-marktplaats&channel=bt_pl&signature=lPDQWiNQ2_mY8xgoVthZHLLYWac='.match(/center\=(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)&/)[1]

console.log(val)
```

> But as other's have commented, you likely shouldn't be using regex for this purpose